# Removing files from GCS: "gsutil -m rm" throws CommandException: files/objects could not be removed

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

```
gsutil -m rm gs://{our_bucket}/{dir}/{subdir}/*

...
Removing gs://our_bucket/dir/subdir/staging-000000000102.json...
Removing gs://our_bucket/dir/subdir/staging-000000000101.json...
CommandException: 103 files/objects could not be removed.
```

The command is able to find the directory with the 103 .JSON files, and "tries" removing them per the `Removing gs://...` being output. For what reason might we be receiving `CommandException: 103 files/objects could not be removed.`?

- This works on my local machine
- This works in our docker container run locally
- This does not work in our docker container on the GCP compute engine where we need it to be working.

Perhaps this is a permissions issue with the compute engine not having permission to remove files in our GCS?

**Edit:** We have a service account JSON in the `/config` folder of our Airflow project, and that service account is shared to an IAM user with `Storage Admin` permission. Perhaps having the JSON in the /config folder is not sufficient for assigning permissions to the entire GCP compute engine? I am particularly confused because this server **is** able to query from our BQ database, and WRITE to GCS, but cannot delete from GCS...

Comment: The first step is to determine the permissions (roles) that the instance has. Edit your question with those details.

Comment: @JohnHanley see edit. I am beginning to think it is not enough for the service account JSON to be *somewhere* on the server... do we need to do something else to assign permissions to the server?

Comment: when i try to use `gsutil cp`, as opposed to `rm`, i do get a `AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission` error

Answer (score 2):

The solution in this link - https://gist.github.com/ryderdamen/926518ddddd46dd4c8c2e4ef5167243d was exactly what we needed:

- Stop the instance
- Edit the settings
- Remove gsutil cache